# Generating next sequence value manually in Doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

What would be the easiest way to generate `nextval` for some particular sequence with given name?

The annotation solution with specifying

```
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
 * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="sq_foobar", allocationSize="1", initialValue="1")
```

doesn't satisfy me, as long as there is some more complex logic involved: in some cases I need to retrieve `nextval`, in other - I would go with the value retrieved from another sources (not sequence).

So I hope there is a way to retrieve a sequence nextval manually in entity's constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then I think you should implement your own Identitfer Generator.

The easyest would be to override the  Doctrine\ORM\Id\SequenceGenerator class to handle your specific case.

You then have to register this generator in the class metadata using Doctrine ORM API.

Some links: http://ranskills.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/how-to-add-a-custom-id-generation-strategy-to-doctrine-2-1/

https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/206

Comment: The article advices to modify core files :-S

Comment: Yep. It's not possible without modifying core doctrine files, until PR #206 is merged.

Comment: You can maintain your own fork, even if it's not a good idea. But a even worse idea is to mix identifier generation.

Comment: For now I generate it in repository, that acts as an objects' factory

Answer (score 43):

Just in case someone else lands on this question (like I did):
The pull request @Florian mentioned made it into doctrine now. Although documentation seems to still lack any information for the **CUSTOM** id generator strategy. Only part I found where `CUSTOM` option for IdGenerator is mentioned is at [GeneratedValue](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#generatedvalue) description. If I missed it, please correct me in the comments.

Tough it can easily be implemented. Just create an class extending `Doctrine\ORM\Id\AbstractIdGenerator`:

```
namespace My\Namespace;
use Doctrine\ORM\Id\AbstractIdGenerator;
class MyIdGenerator extends AbstractIdGenerator
{
    public function generate(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em, $entity)
    {
        // Create id here
        $id = <do some logic>;
        return $id;
    }
}
```

Then add it to your `id` description in the doctrine entity configuration (`YAML` example):

```
My\Bundle\Entity\MyEntity:
    type: entity
    id:
        id:
            type: bigint
            unique: true
            generator:
                strategy: CUSTOM
            customIdGenerator:
                class: 'My\Namespace\MyIdGenerator'
    fields:
        otherField: ....
```

If you use `Annotations` instead of YAML, the entity configuration should look like this (untested):

```
/**
  * @Id 
  * @Column(type="integer")
  * @GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
  * @CustomIdGenerator(class="My\Namespace\MyIdGenerator")
  */
  public $id;
```

And thats all ;)

Answer (score 22):

There are two possibilities getting sequence nextval in Doctrine2:

1. Use Doctrine ORM SequenceGenerator

   ```
   use Doctrine\ORM\Id\SequenceGenerator;
   $sequenceName = 'file_id_seq';
   $sequenceGenerator = new SequenceGenerator($sequenceName, 1);
   $newId = $sequenceGenerator->generate($entityManager, $entity);
   // $entity in this case is actually not used in generate() method, so you can give any empty object, or if you are not worried about editor/IDE warnings, you can also specify null
   ```
2. Use native SQL

   ```
   $sequenceName = 'file_id_seq';
   $dbConnection = $entityManager->getConnection();
   $nextvalQuery = $dbConnection->getDatabasePlatform()->getSequenceNextValSQL($sequenceName);
   // $nextvalQuery is now following string "SELECT NEXTVAL('file_id_seq')"
   $newId = (int)$dbConnection->fetchColumn($nextvalQuery);
   ```

Comment: I don't remember now - but for some reason such obvious solutions didn't fit my requirements, but it was too long ago, so +1 for your time ;-)

Comment: for non pk columns only the second variant is a solution

Comment: If you use allocationSize > 1, eg: allocationSize="100", the second solution will not work correctly, as it will jump 100 values every time.

Comment: Without sequence name hardcode: `$em->getClassMetadata(TestInterest::class)->idGenerator->generate($em, null)`

Comment: @zerkms it doesn't satisfy you probably because the Doctrine is performing NEXTVAL() call every time before flushing it into DB. Calling it manually before Doctrine makes no sense because it will cause double id generation and you anyway won't know the real id. You'll get 1 but in the DB it will be 2 because of double NEXTVAL() calls. So this way doesn't work with SEQUENCE strategy.

Answer (score 0):

I have symfony 6 with doctrine-orm 2.13 and works with code,
In SomeEntityRepository created function:

```
public function fetchSeqId(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager){
    $dbConnection = $entityManager->getConnection();
    $nextValQuery = $dbConnection->getDatabasePlatform()->getSequenceNextValSQL('some_id_seq');        
    $id = (int) $dbConnection->executeQuery($nextValQuery)->fetchOne();
    return $id;
}
```

and use in controller as:

```
$repository = $this->entityManager->getRepository(SomeEntity::class);
$id= $repository->fetchSeqId($this->entityManager);
```