# In doctrine2 is it possible to have an autoincrement column that is not the primary key?

Tags: zend-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm, primary-key, auto-increment

In doctrine2 I have an entity that has a primary key that's feeded from a webservice, and also has an index that should be an auto increment.

I can set manually in mysql but can't make this work in doctrine2.

Comment: As Doctrine seems to limit autoincrement to id fields, did you find a workaround?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The auto-increment limitation is related to the database you are using.
in Mysql ,[Mysql_autoincrement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html),  it also depends on the engine you are using.
exemple:

> For MyISAM and BDB tables you can specify AUTO_INCREMENT on a
>   secondary column in a multiple-column index. In this case, the
>   generated value for the AUTO_INCREMENT column is calculated as

You can have a general documentation on auto_increment [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp)

In general the auto_increment is reserved to a numerical field that is part of the identifier index (one or more column involved).

So this can work for mysql.

However  the auto_incriment in doctrine seems to only be alllowed for THe @Id (Primary Key)

> 21.2.9. @GeneratedValue
>
> Specifies which strategy is used for identifier generation for an
>   instance variable which is annotated by @Id. This annotation is
>   optional and only has meaning when used in conjunction with @Id.
>
> If this annotation is not specified with @Id the NONE strategy is used
>   as default.
>
> Required attributes:
>
> strategy: Set the name of the identifier generation strategy. Valid
>   values are AUTO, SEQUENCE, TABLE, IDENTITY, UUID, CUSTOM and NONE.
>   Example:

```
?php
/**
 * @Id
 * @Column(type="integer")
 * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id = null;
```

[Doctrine_auto_increment](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-generatedvalue)

You may want to find a work arround and post a ticket about it

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli at the time yes but 6 years later i am not sure, but it seems that Auto is still based on what is availabl on Mysql. Maybe what you need is UUID strategy ? . Check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14029064/1427338

Answer (score 23):

I used `columnDefinition` of `INT AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE`

```php
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="sequence", nullable=true, columnDefinition="INT AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE")
 */
protected $sequence = null;
```

Doctrine migration bundle generates

```php
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE table_name_here ADD sequence INT AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE');
```

Edit: Note that this answer is from 2016, it may no longer be valid. See accepted answer.

Comment: still valid on doctrine/orm v2.6.2

Comment: If I use `columnDefinition` and insert a new record into the table, will the entity be updated with the autogenerated autoincremented value?

Comment: Also, `columnDefinition` leads to a situation when `doctrine:migrations:diff` generates the same SQL statement in both UP and DOWN migrations, e.g. `ALTER TABLE users_interests CHANGE id id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL
` - this query is the same in both UP and DOWN migrations.

Comment: This is so great, simple and still works.