# Symfony 3 Doctrine Composite Key: single id is not allowed on composite primary key in entity

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

I have an entity with an

> integer column (compositeId)

and a

> string column (asin)

I want both columns working as a composite key.
So I look here in the documentation:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html

But when I try to load my repository

```
$myEntity = $em->getRepository(MyEntity::class);
```

I got this error message:

> single id is not allowed on composite primary key in entity
>   AppBundle\Entity\MyEntity

This is my Entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;


use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\MyEntityRepository")
 * @Table(name="my_entity")
 */
class MyEntity {

    /**
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue()
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer", name="composite_id")
     */
    protected $compositeId;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="string", name="asin")
     */
    protected $asin;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Column(type="string", name="sku")
     */
    protected $sku;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Column(type="string", name="ean")
     */
    protected $ean;

    /**
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId() {

        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $id
     *
     * @return MyEntity;
     */
    public function setId($id) {

        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     * @return int
     */
    public function getCompositeId() {

        return $this->compositeId;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $compositeId
     *
     * @return MyEntity;
     */
    public function setCompositeId($compositeId) {

        $this->compositeId = $compositeId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAsin() {

        return $this->asin;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $asin
     *
     * @return MyEntity;
     */
    public function setAsin($asin) {

        $this->asin = $asin;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSku() {

        return $this->sku;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $sku
     *
     * @return MyEntity;
     */
    public function setSku($sku) {

        $this->sku = $sku;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEan() {

        return $this->ean;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $ean
     *
     * @return MyEntity;
     */
    public function setEan($ean) {

        $this->ean = $ean;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
When I remove @generatedValue at my ID table it works.
But I need auto generated values at my ID column.
I don't have any @Id annotation at my ID column, only @generatedValue, and on my both @Id columns I don't have any annotation with @generatedValue but I got this error ...

Comment: May be you don't need this, `/**
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue()
     */
    protected $id;`

Comment: yes.. when I remove @generatedValue at the column ID this works. But what ... If I want to add new entries with generated IDs in the future?

Comment: What do you mean by generated ID? Sequence ids ?

Comment: yes I mean auto generated Ids when I create a new row in my table

Comment: Just remove `@Id` attribute in that, so it won't be considered as a Table primary key.

Comment: I don't have any @ Id annotation at my ID column, only @ generatedValue, and on my both @ Id columns I don't have any annotation with @ generatedValuebut I got this error ...

Answer (score 1):

Doctrine only supports `@GeneratedValue()` on `@Id` fields.

> This annotation is optional and only has meaning when used in conjunction with @Id.

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref_generatedvalue

You may be able to use `columnDefinition` as a workaround, e.g.

`@ORM\Column(type="integer", name="id", columnDefinition="INT AUTO_INCREMENT")`

as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34749619/380054

Answer (score -7):

You need to remove all `@Id` in properties description except protected `$id`.