# Doctrine2 + Symfony2 Sequence ID Table

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to retrieve the `id` value from `vtiger_crmentity_seq` in order to update `vtiger_crmentity.crmid` becase it isn't `auto_increment`

So this is my entity `vtiger_crmentity`

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="crmid", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
 * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="vtiger_crmentity_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
 */
private $crmid;

/**
 * Get crmid
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getCrmid()
{
    return $this->crmid;
}
```

But when I try to submit my form, Symfony2 returns me this error.

> Operation
>   'Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform::getSequenceNextValSQL' is
>   not supported by platform. 500 Internal Server Error - DBALException

I cannot change `vtiger_crmentity.crmid` to `auto_increment` so this idea is discarted, also I need to update `vtiger_crmentity_seq.id` to the latest value used obviously...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try with a custom generator, with custom generator you can solve any primary key generation problem.

this code calls some native query in sql, but you can do really everything in your custom generator.

```
<?php

namespace MY\Doctrine;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Id\AbstractIdGenerator;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query;

class CustomGenerator extends AbstractIdGenerator
{
    static $cache = array();

    public function generate(EntityManager $em, $entity)
    {
        $id = $em->createNativeQuery(
                'SELECT crmid FROM vtiger_crmentity_seq WHERE used = 0 LIMIT 1',
                new Query\ResultSetMapping()
            )->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_SINGLE_SCALAR);
        $em->getConnection()->executeUpdate(
            'UPDATE vtiger_crmentity_seq SET used = 1 WHERE crmid = ?', 
             array($id)
        )

        return $id;
    }
}
```

and in your entity

```
...
class AbstractProduct
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="ID", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
     * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="\My\CustomGenerator")
     */
    protected $id;
...
```

Comment: Is this ID setted on calling the constructor or when we persist/update the entity?

Comment: neither, it's called after the prePersist event

Answer (score 4):

Doctrine does not support using the `SEQUENCE` strategy for `GeneratedValue` when using MySQL. If you cannot set the column to `auto_increment`, you'll have to generate the IDs in your own code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14022374/the-differences-between-generatedvalue-strategies).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, also I'm looking the page you said but I don't see how can I generate the IDs in my own code... I think it'll be useful when  TableGenerator is supported but now, I'm a bit lost :/

Comment: As a workaround, you could set the strategy to `NONE` and generate your own IDs, similar to here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/sharding.html#table-generator

Comment: But actually there's no method for do `nextValue` to anything, I mean, the only way I can handle all of this is what I'm doing right now: `$id = QueryTableSeq->getId` then when inserting do `QueryTableSet->DoSomeQueryForIdField($id+1)` and `MyData->setId($id)`

Comment: I've made a simple annotation that worked:

`/**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="id", initialValue=100)
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;`