# GeneratedValue counter for Id resets every time that the server and client are executed

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, primary-key, generated

I'm working on a JavaEE application with EJB and JPA.

My Entities, are defined, for instance, like this:

```
@Entity
public class Utente implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int cod_utente;
private String nome_utente;
private String morada_utente;
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private GregorianCalendar dnasc_utente;
private int tel_utente;
private List<GregorianCalendar> agenda;
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(nullable=true)
private List<Prescricao> lista_presc;
```

When I create entities *Utente*, the keys are generated sequentially starting from one. If I shut down the clients and server and execute them again, the "counter" of the key generator is reestablished. This results in an error because the application will try to create another *Utente* with primary key "1".

Can please someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: AFAIK it should work. Have you tried manually setting a different generation strategy?

Comment: BTW, which JPA provider? Which DB system? Are JPA properties set to that dialect?

Comment: I'm using glassfish. The JPA provider is EclipseLink

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int cod_utente;
```

doesn't set a specific stategy to generate the values for the ID.

It is the same as this code:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int cod_utente;
```

[`GenerationType.AUTO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/GenerationType.html#AUTO) means that the persistence provider (in Glassfish the default persistence provider is EclipseLink) should choose an appropriate strategy for the database you are using. It looks like the persistence provider is choosing a strategy which is restarting the values after a server restart in your case.

There are different generation strategies, you can find some detailed information in the [EclipseLink Wiki](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/PrimaryKey).

I guess your best bet is to use a database sequence (`GenerationType.SEQUENCE`) to generate the ID values.

Example:

Create a database sequence named `GEN_SEQUENCE` (if you let the persistence provider generate your tables I guess you can also let it create the sequence somehow but this example will show how to do it manually), you should look for information on how to do that in the database you are using (probably something like `CREATE SEQUENCE gen_sequence;`). Change your code to this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "my_seq_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "my_seq_gen", sequenceName = "GEN_SEQUENCE")
private int cod_utente;
```

You can also use the same sequence for different classes.

**Update:**

For the [`@SequenceGenerator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html) you can set an **allocationSize**, this value is the amount of sequence values which get reserved. The default value is 50. When you have a sequence which starts at 0, the first time a value is requested from the sequence, the sequence allocates (and reserves) the values 0-49 (or 1-50). These values can be used by the persistence provider until all values have been used, then the next 50 values (50-99 or 51-100) will get allocated and reserved. The sequence remembers the current position, so that it doesn't give out the same range twice if it is used by multiple classes.

For the value of the **allocationSize** you can keep the default, but this may produce gaps in the IDs. If a sequence range (e.g. 0-49) gets allocated (reserved) and only one or some of the values are used (e.g. 0, 1 and 2) the other values of this range (3-49) will get "lost" on server restart. The next time a range of values is allocated it will be 50-99, so the next ID in your table will be 50. 
Now you have the following IDs in your table: `0,1,2,50`. Normally this shouldn't be a problem, but you can also set the **allocationSize** to a lower value or to **1** to avoid creating such gaps.

**See also:**

- [what is the use of annotations @Id and @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)? Why the generationtype is identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603638/what-is-the-use-of-annotations-id-and-generatedvaluestrategy-generationtype)
- [what is sequence (Database) ? When we need it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649102/what-is-sequence-database-when-we-need-it)
- [The differences between GeneratedValue strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14022374/the-differences-between-generatedvalue-strategies)

Comment: to use that strategy we need to set an `allocationSize` right? To what does that value correspond? what's the criterion to set that value?

Comment: I wrote this code in my entities:

`@Id
 @SequenceGenerator(name="seq7", initialValue=1, allocationSize=100)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="seq7")
 private int cod_ficha;`

But this error occurred while running the server:

`xception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: SEQUENCE 'SEQ7' does not exist.
Error Code: 30000
Call: VALUES(NEXT VALUE FOR seq7)
Query: ValueReadQuery(sql="VALUES(NEXT VALUE FOR seq7)")`

Comment: The error message says, the sequence does not exist. As described in the answer you have to create the sequence manually on the database.