# PostgreSQL: ramsey/uuid-doctrine vs doctrine's UUID strategy with type guid

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

The setup is doctrine 2.8 and a PostgreSQL database 13.2. I'm trying to understand the difference in using ramsey/uuid-doctrine vs the doctrine's own UUID strategy with guid as type.

ramsey/uuid-doctrine example:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @var \Ramsey\Uuid\UuidInterface
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="uuid", unique=true)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
     * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class=UuidGenerator::class)
     */
    protected $id;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

doctrine's own UUID strategy with it's own guid type, which maps to UUID on PostgreSQL:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     * @ORM\Column(type="guid")
     */
    private $id;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Question:

- What is the difference, benefits or drawbacks of one or the other method. Please keep in mind that the database is PostgreSQL which natively handles the UUID as binary.

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know what's really going on with the two methods, but the UUID strategy seems **deprecated** as for Doctrine 3.0 and should be replaced with a **CUSTOM** strategy, and thus a custom id generator (which should be extending Doctrine's AbstractIdGenerator).

You can see the *deprecated* tag in [this very section](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifier-generation-strategies).

As for the drawbacks of this particular method, I don't know but I suppose in exchange for more control (you have to implement your generator), it's a bit more heavy than ramsey/uuid-doctrine.

I think it really depends on your needs and maybe on your ability to use third party libraries:
if, like me, you work on big projects in a big company and if you are fighting against a lot of corporate cybersecurity rules, this might just be the only way to go.

A little more info on the [custom strategy implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087585/generating-next-sequence-value-manually-in-doctrine-2/28561017#28561017).

EDIT: It's actually the same thing because the 2 methods are CUSTOM strategies. Except one (ramsey's) take care of the implementation for you. The other one lets you generate whatever value you need (not just UUIDs).